# Store an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm creating a program to automatize the train logical system, using Java.
I want store trains with ArrayList:

`ArrayList<Treni> train = new ArrayList<>();`

and add a multiple stations to the train list:

```
ArrayList<Fermata> stop= new ArrayList<>();
stop.add(new Stop("Milan", "7", new DepartureTime((byte) 19, (byte) 35)));
train.add(new Train(87569, "Trenitalia", fermata));
```

Now i want to clear all stops to add a new stops:

`stop.clear();`

but with this method it clear the stops in entire class Train. How can i store the ArrayList stop and use the method *clear();* without lose stops in the Train class?

This is Train.java:

````
public class Train{
  private int number;
  private String owner;
  private ArrayList<Stop> stop = new ArrayList<>();

  Train(int number, String owner, ArrayList<Fermata> stop) {
    this.number = number;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.stop = stop;
  }
}

class Stop{
  String station, binary;
  DepartureTime departure;
  ArrivalTime arrival;

  Stop(String station, String binary, DepartureTime departure, ArrivalTime arrival) {
    this.station= station;
    this.binary= binary;
    this.departure= departure;
    this.arrival= arrival;
  }

  Stop(String station, String binary, DepartureTime departure) {
    this.station = station;
    this.binary= binary;
    this.departure= departure;
  }
}

class DepartureTime{
  private byte hour, minute;

  DepartureTime(byte hour, byte minute) {
    this.hour= hour;
    this.minute = minute;
  }

}

class ArrivalTime {
  private byte hour, minute;

  ArrivalTime (byte hour, byte minute) {
    this.hour= hour;
    this.minute = minute;
  }
}```
````

Comment: Just create a new `List` instead of `clear`ing the old one: `stop = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: And hint: the primary language here is English. It is very unfortunate when you come with code that **partially** uses identifiers in a different language, especially, when you use some of those terms here and there in your text, too. Be consistent, and ideally: take the few minutes it takes to ensure that your identifiers are consistent, too (and ideally: in English)

Comment: The problem with `this.stop = stop` is that it stores the `ArrayList` passed to the method into the `stop` field. These variables refer to the same list, and changes to the list will be visible to all variables referring to that list. It's like attaching two strings to a green balloon and then painting the balloon red.

Comment: Instead of writing `this.stop = stop`, you could also use `this.stop.addAll(stop)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Answer by Zidek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71779546/642706) is correct, and should be accepted. Here I will give some example code, while rewriting for brevity.

You can define your classes more briefly as [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). Records are appropriate for classes whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably.

You can use `List.of` to instantiate an unmodifiable `List` object.

Rather than invent your own type for time-of-day, use `java.time.LocalTime`.

By the way, a train number should be of type String (or a custom class), not an integer type. The train number is really a train *identifier*, not a quantity nor an ordinal.

This code is untested, written in an iPhone, so may need some editing.

```java
public record Train( int number, String owner, List<Stop> stops ) {}
```

```java
public record Stop( String station, String binary, LocalTime departure, LocalTime arrival ) {}
```

```java
List< Train > trains = 
    List.of( 
        new Train(
            87569, 
            "Trenitalia", 
            List.of( 
                new Stop( "Milan", "7", LocalTime.of( 19 , 35 ), null ) ,
                new Stop( "Venice", "7", LocalTime.of( 20 , 55 ) , null ) 
            )
        ) ,
        … new Train( … )
    );
```

If you need a list to be modifiable, instantiate `ArrayList`. But note that you can pass to its constructor a list produced by `List.of`. This technique makes for compact readable literals-style syntax.

```
List< Person > persons = 
    new ArrayList <>(
        List.of(
            new Person( "Alice" ) , 
            new Person( "Bob" ) ,
            new Person( "Carol" ) 
        )
    )
;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is suggested in the @f1sh's and @MCEmperor's comments.

For some reasons, there is a meme among the programmers, that creating a new object is always more costly than recycling an old one. This is what probably misleads you to use `stop.clear()` instead of `stop = new ArrayList<Stop>`.

By the way, it's a good practice to name list variables in plural, so `stops` would be a much better name than `stop` for a list of stops.

There is probably other misunderstanding in your question. The parameters in Java are **always** passed as "reference by value". So what you are passing to your train is a reference to a list. Your `Train` object does not receive a copy of the list of stops, but just a reference to its memory representation in heap. So if you later change the content of the memory, your train refers to the new data.

On the other side, when you change the outside `stops` variable, the original memory will remain the same.

So just do as @f1sh says: "just create a new List instead of clearing the old one: `stops = new ArrayList<>();`"

Answer (score 0):

You fell in a well known Java trap: the argument `stop` of the constructor `Train(int,String,List<Stop>)` is *not* an (instance of an) `ArrayList`, it is just the *reference* to such an instance.

This means that the statement

```
this.stop = stop;
```

in that constructor does not keep an instance of that `List`, but just a reference.

As a consequence you should have noticed that all trains would have exactly the same list of stops when you do omit the call to `stop.clear()`.

You now have two options to fix this:

1. Instead of calling clear on the `stop` list, you create a new instance, by calling `new ArrayList<Stop>`.
2. The recommended approach (as the first one is far from being bullet proof …) looks like this:

```
public class Train
{
  private final int number;
  private final String owner;
  private final List<Stop> stop;

  Train( final int number, final String owner, final List<Stop> stop ) 
  {
    this.number = number;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.stop = List.copyOf( stop );
  }
}
```

If you want to manipulate the stops later, you can also write

```
this.stop = new ArrayList<>( stop );
```

Copied from the [closed duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71780933/1554195).