# Stack an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm creating a program to automate the train logistics system, using Java. I want store trains with ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Train> train = new ArrayList<>();
```

and add a multiple stations to the train list:

```
ArrayList<Stop> stop= new ArrayList<>();
stop.add( new Stop( "Milan", "7", new DepartureTime( (byte) 19, (byte) 35 ) ) );
train.add( new Train( 87569, "Trenitalia", stop ) );
```

Now i want to clear all stops to add a new stops:

```
stop.clear();
```

but with this method it clear the stops in entire class `Train`. How can I store the `ArrayList stop` and use the method `clear()` without lose stops in the `Train` class?

This is `Train.java`:

```
public class Train{
  private int number;
  private String owner;
  private ArrayList<Stop> stop = new ArrayList<>();

  Train(int number, String owner, ArrayList<Stop> stop) {
    this.number = number;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.stop = stop;
  }
}

class Stop{
  String station, binary;
  DepartureTime departure;
  ArrivalTime arrival;

  Stop(String station, String binary, DepartureTime departure, ArrivalTime arrival) {
    this.station= station;
    this.binary= binary;
    this.departure= departure;
    this.arrival= arrival;
  }

  Stop(String station, String binary, DepartureTime departure) {
    this.station = station;
    this.binary= binary;
    this.departure= departure;
  }
}

class DepartureTime{
  private byte hour, minute;

  DepartureTime(byte hour, byte minute) {
    this.hour= hour;
    this.minute = minute;
  }

}

class ArrivalTime {
  private byte hour, minute;

  ArrivalTime (byte hour, byte minute) {
    this.hour= hour;
    this.minute = minute;
  }
}
```

Comment: is that a typo `ArrayList<Fermata> stop`

Comment: If you are clearing the stop arraylist, then because that list is in Train, the list in train will also get cleared, as it is the same list, and not a copy of iy

Comment: This is the same question as [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71778942/store-an-arraylist). Please don't post your question twice.

Comment: @MCEmperor – He probably did not grasp the answers to that other one …

Comment: @tquadrat Probably, but even then it's [not okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278510/what-to-do-if-a-user-asks-the-same-question-twice) to ask a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fell in a well known Java trap: the argument `stop` of the constructor `Train(int,String,List<Stop>)` is *not* an (instance of an) `ArrayList`, it is just the *reference* to such an instance.

This means that the statement

```
this.stop = stop;
```

in that constructor does not keep an instance of that `List`, but just a reference.

As a consequence you should have noticed that all trains would have exactly the same list of stops when you do omit the call to `stop.clear()`.

You now have two options to fix this:

1. Instead of calling clear on the `stop` list, you create a new instance, by calling `new ArrayList<Stop>`.
2. The recommended approach (as the first one is far from being bullet proof …) looks like this:

```
public class Train
{
  private final int number;
  private final String owner;
  private final List<Stop> stop;

  Train( final int number, final String owner, final List<Stop> stop ) 
  {
    this.number = number;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.stop = List.copyOf( stop );
  }
}
```

If you want to manipulate the stops later, you can also write

```
this.stop = new ArrayList<>( stop );
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `stop` is added `train` it is still the same reference you're clearing.
So, Create a shallow copy of the `Stop` ArrayList and add it to `Train`, something like this.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        ArrayList<Train> train = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Stop> stop= new ArrayList<>();
        stop.add(new Stop("Milan", "7", new DepartureTime((byte) 19, (byte) 35)));

        ArrayList<Stop>  copyStop = new ArrayList<>(stop);
        train.add(new Train(87569, "Trenitalia", new ArrayList<>(copyStop)));
        stop.clear();

    }
```